# How can I acquire copies of insurance claims not by me?

Tags: discussion

I don't want get banned or get my question closed again by moderator. Just checking if this question is on topic on the main?

---

In 2016 my mom bought a NEW  car as clearly stated on the contract. Because the same problems recurred, on Jan 1 2020 I bought a CarProof report that lists Insurance Claims before 2016 with only the date, Location (ON, Canada), Type of Claim, and Amount. I know her car's VIN. How can I obtain copies of these Claims with just these scant details? Discovery starts on Jan 1 2020 as per the [*Limitations Act, 2002* s 5](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/02l24).

Comment: It would help if you explained why you think it might be on-topic. My initial sense is that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is Canadian specific I would be unable to give an answer to the question.

But upon seeing this question on the main site I would ask you:

- How many miles were on the new car when it was purchased?
- You mention that the car was purchased in 2016. But what model year was the car? and what month in 2016 was the purchase?
- Does Carproof have an option for getting a more detailed report?
- You said: "same problems recurred". What problems? and are they covered by the warranty or a recall notice?

So details are needed.

Unless something with a big clue comes from these details, I would guess that you need to talk to a consumer complaint lawyer.